# Socket Communicatin BufferedReader

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I dont know much about buffer readers but mine hangs up at the line where it is supposed to read it any suggestions

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Host
{

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
     ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5001);
     Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",5001);
     s=ss.accept();

     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);

     writer.write("Time");
     writer.println("time");

     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

     String test =reader.readLine();
     System.out.println(test);
     s.close();
     ss.close();
}
```

}

Comment: For Clarification the line it hangs up on is String test =  reader.readLine();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peer isn't sending a line or closing the socket. Reason:

```
Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",5001);
```

Here you are creating a connection to yourself.

```
 s=ss.accept();
```

Here you are throwing away that `Socket` and accepting a new one, which is now your end of the connection whose other end you just threw away.

```
String test =reader.readLine();
```

Here you are trying to read a line from the peer which can never arrive, as the peer is yourself and you have thrown away the `Socket.`

You don't need to initialize any variable when you assign it on the very next line. It should be:

```
Socket s = ss.accept();
```

Comment: The Problem I have with that is now it hangs up on the Socket = ss.accept(); line

Comment: It's waiting for a client to connect. That's what it's supposed to do, not a problem.

Comment: Your code is a server. It needs a client. That's what it's waiting for. Have you written one? If not, start now. Or use `telnet`.